# Cause of Jobconf exceeed in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a MapReduce Job which runs on daily basis. But it failed with the below exception :-

java.io.IOException: Exceeded max jobconf size: 5437618 limit: 5242880.

Can I know the root cause of this. The input path of the job remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the parameter values got really big.  Try to debug by using the iterator() method on JobConf to traverse the set of key/value pairs to see if one of those values is inordinately large.